# Way to take a JSON object from a REST call and populate a Class

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm developing some automation that connects to a REST service on some storage devices. The REST service returns data in JSON format that works nicely with python.

I have the following class (simplified here) that performs the REST-query in itself and then assigns it to class variables:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, client):
        # my rest code <SNIPPED>
        self.data = myresults.data() # data is now a dictionary with my rest results

        # I now want to break data{} down into individual self.XXXX variables
        self.var1     = self.data['var1']
        self.var2     = self.data['var2']
```

Is there a trick to doing this without "brute forcing" it like my example above? This dict contains quite a few keys. Most are numeric in type and will be involved in calculations and it gets real clunky using dict notation.

Or is there a better approach than what I'm trying to do? Doing it this way doesn't really solve what I want to achieve:

```
self.data{} = None
self.data   = myresults.data()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#setattr) on an instance of the class.

```
for (key, value) in self.data:
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: I actually found what I was looking for and now wanna kick myself repeatedly for not finding this sooner. (self.__dict__ = self.rawdata) However, what you provide is also useful in other places so I'll accept your answer! Thx!